# Wysihat without Rake, just Javascript?

Tags: javascript, rake, wysihat

Is there a way to install and use Wysihat without running Rake? I naively tried copying source javascript-files from online examples of Wysihat, but I get the warning that I should "run Rake in the project root".

Second, I tried to get Rake (whatever it may be). But nowhere I found a decent article on how to get it up and running, let alone how to use it. I see words like 'git', 'gem' and 'command line' (at least know what that is) all over the place, but I don't know where to start.

Taken in account the problems from above, I could have asked another question instead: how to install and use Rake? But my main problem is: I want to get Wysihat to work, with or without Rake.

Thanks in advance for your reply!

*Yes, I understand that I miss a certain understanding about Rake (or other build-stuff). It is there with a reason, probably. I'm a PHP-developer and never needed to use Rake.*

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem. Until you find how to run that rake file, you can get wysihat.js [here](https://github.com/tiff/wysihat-extended-demo/blob/master/wysihat.js).

Comment: Thanks, I found a way to get Wysihat up and running. I used Bitnami Rubystack and some tutorials to get it working. Once I got it working I was able to copy the generated files and reuse them in other projects.
I am still wondering what Rake does exactly and why it's necessary for Wysihat. But anyway, it works and Wysihat is a great tool I have long been waiting for.